# PHP to WCF calls with dictionary type parameters

Tags: php, web-services, wcf, dictionary

How can I call WCF web service using php with parameter dictionary type.
For example server side c# function like

> public int Add(string name, Dictionary address) { // do some thing }

In client side php code like as-

```
$sh_param = array('name' => 'someone', 'address' => ?? ); 
$info = $soapClient->__soapCall("Add", array($sh_param));
```

here what would be the type of address in php client

Comment: how does the WSDL looks like?

Comment: [link](https://247vqatest10.247salescenter.com/WCFServices/ContactsSync.svc?wsdl)

Answer (score 0):

```
$sh_param = array('name' => 'someone', 
                  'address' => array(array('Key'=>'','Value'=>''),
                   ...));
```

Parameter：
Dictionary => Key,Value

For example：
server side c# function like

```
public bool Add(Dictionary<int,string> address){....}
```

In client side php code like

```
$address=array(
array('Key'=>1,'Value'=>'Huntington Beach'),
array('Key'=>2,'Value'=>'Los Angeles')
......
);

client = new SoapClient('....');
$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->address = $address;
$result = $client->Add($obj);
$result = $result->AddResult;
```

Comment: I don't know why the downvote, you just saved me at least a day of work, thank you! :)